# After upgrading to the latest version : org.specs2.execute.Failure required: T

Tags: scala

After upgrading my scala to latest version i got that error:

> type mismatch;  found   : org.specs2.execute.Failure  required: T

My code:

```
  def shouldThrow[T <: Exception](exClazz: Class[T])(body: => Unit): T = {
    try {
      body
    } catch {
      case e: Throwable =>
        if (e.getClass == exClazz) return e.asInstanceOf[T]
        val failure = new Failure("Expected %s but got %s".format(exClazz, e.getClass), "", new Exception().getStackTrace.toList, org.specs2.execute.NoDetails())                                                 
        val rethrown = new FailureException(failure)
        rethrown.initCause(e)
        throw rethrown

    }
    failure("Exception expected, but has not been thrown")
  }
```

I got this error at last line `failure("...")`

Any idea whats goin on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the message says, method `failure` returns a `Failure`, but you tell the compiler you want to return `T`. You can just throw an exception in the last line (which `failure` probably used to do). You can also avoid passing `Class[T]` manually by using `ClassTag`:

```
def shouldThrow[T <: Exception](body: => Unit)(implicit ct: ClassTag[T]): T = {
  ... // as before
  case e: Throwable =>
    val exClass = ct.runtimeClass
    ... // as before
}

// usage
shouldThrow[IOException] {
  // body
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`failure` in mutable specifications used to be defined without a return type and then it return type was `Nothing`. This has been fixed to return `Failure` and be more consistent with non-mutable specifications.

However you don't need `failure` in your code because there are exceptions matchers (see the "Exception" tab [here](http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.Matchers.html#Out+of+the+box)) and you can write:

```
body must throwAn[IllegalArgumentException]
```